# How can one sort data in r based on a condition being met and time ordering?

Tags: r, sorting, data-manipulation

If I have the below dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
           x = c("no","yes","no","no","no","yes", "no"),
           y= c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))
```

| ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | no | 1 |
| 1 | yes | 2 |
| 1 | no | 3 |
| 1 | no | 4 |
| 2 | no | 1 |
| 2 | no | 2 |
| 2 | yes | 3 |
| 2 | no | 4 |

ID is an identifier, x tells us whether or not a condition has been met, and y is a time order unique to each ID (though in a real data set it would probably be a date). How can I remove rows where the condition was not met but keep rows where the condition was met, or the event occurred after the condition was met?

A final result should look like this:

| ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | yes | 2 |
| 1 | no | 3 |
| 1 | no | 4 |
| 2 | yes | 3 |
| 2 | no | 4 |

Comment: Copying the dataframe, code returns an error `Error in data.frame  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R option using `ave` + `subset`

```
subset(
  df,
  ave(x == "yes", ID, FUN = cumsum) > 0
)
```

gives

```
  ID   x y
2  1 yes 2
3  1  no 3
4  1  no 4
7  2 yes 3
8  2  no 4
```

---

A `data.table` option following the same idea as above is

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[cumsum(x == "yes") > 0], ID]
   ID   x y
1:  1 yes 2
2:  1  no 3
3:  1  no 4
4:  2 yes 3
5:  2  no 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a logical expression with `cumsum` on the 'x' value of 'yes' after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(cumsum(x == 'yes') >0) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#     ID x         y
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1     1 yes       2
#2     1 no        3
#3     1 no        4
#4     2 yes       3
#5     2 no        4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` to get the index of first `'yes'` for each `ID` and use it in `filter` or `slice`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(row_number() >= match('yes', x)) %>%
  ungroup
```

With `slice` :

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(match('yes', x):n()) %>%
  ungroup
```